# Resizing the content inside of an iframe (Axure project)

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, prototype, axure

I have a project on Axshare that I'm trying to include in my portfolio (you can view it here: https://fzm84s.axshare.com/#g=1&p=home_page).

I added an iframe in Wordpress, but the whole project only shows up if I specify that the frame is 1000x1200px. This is too large to display well on my portfolio site, so I tried using % instead, but then the iframe size is reduced without reducing the size of the content within it.

Is there any way to display the project within the iframe smaller? Or will I have to go back in to Axure and make the entire project half the pixel size that it currently is?

Any help, guidance, or recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: the problem is with your iframe content. It has some min-width rules which should add scroll in the iframe. I think, the fastest and easiest way is to go to Axure and wrote @media queries for the screen sizes you're using for iframe